# Get the Value of a Child Node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am looking at a node in the JS console, that has one child node I  need to access. Let's say the parent node is called "blocks" and the child node is called "details_49_2".

```
>blocks:
   >details_49_2:
      id : '2'
      >stuff:
      >lots_of_stuff:
      >lots_more_stuff:
```

[image]

That child node is full of information I need to get at; the only problem is the node changes from page-to-page, so I can't hard-code it's name as a variable. I can access the information perfectly fine, if I hard code the information blocks.details_49_2.id, for instance, but it's variable, depending on the page. I know this is the only child node and the first child, but I am not sure how to get the node's name from JS. childNodes and getFirstChild seem to only deal with the actual HTML DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can determine the property name during runtime, then you could use bracket access notation to access it:

```
const name = 'details_42_2';
const subObject = blocks[name];
```

However, if you have no means to determine its name but you know it is the only property of `blocks`, then you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
const subObject = Object.values(blocks)[0];
```

Here is an example:

```js
const data = { blocks: { details_42_2: { id: '2' } } };

console.log(Object.values(data.blocks)[0]);
```

Comment: The second option  works perfectly; it's just what I needed. Thank you.